# Undefined control seqeunece.\ documentclass

Tags: documentclass-writing, undefined, documentclass

may u help me with this error When I write this simple command in texstudio?when I type \ documnet class the error will apppear but when I typ doc.. and then the software propose default the phrase \documentclass in the box and I choose it'it, the command works appropriate!!  I think beacuase I dont type it! But both commands and letters are exactly the same. while this code is correct:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello world
\end{document}
```

.the errors are:

(1_: undifiend control sequnece..\documentclass

2_missing\begin{document}'\class{a

3_the font size command\ normalize is not defined there is probably something wrong with tge class file.\begin{document})

What are the causes? And how I can solve these bugs?

Comment: most likely you are using plain tex not latex check which command you ran from the editor menu it should be `pdflatex` not `pdftex`

Comment: Thanks. and how can I change my command from pdftex to pdflatex?

Comment: I don't use texstudio so I can't give specific help with its menu system but just check your configuration or wait a bit, a texstudio user will be able to answer.

Comment: Have you installed a TeX distribution before compiling, such as [https://miktex.org/](https://miktex.org/)? If yes, then it should work. However, you can check your compiler in TeXStudio by going to the top ribbon and doing: `Options -> Configure TeX Studio -> Build. Then in default compiler select PDFLaTeX`. Your document works fine for me.

Comment: Tnx jes I changed that and I select pdfl a tex that but i still have the problem